# Where should the app be stored in windows 8 (which folder) in order to work with UAC?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8.1

The problem is My app should run under standard user account with the UAC enabled.

The application itself requires administrative privileges (A windows is shown to enter password for administrator account in order to run application with unknown publisher)

I thought initially that the location of the application matters but probably it is not enough.

I tried to configure runas to run app from standard user account:

runas /user:ComputerName\Administrator /savecred "C:\Path\Program.exe"

but I get error 740: the requested operation requires elevation ... –

Is there another way to run application with admin rights?

Comment: Don't specify `/savecred` as an option?

Comment: are you looking for a method to restart application with Administration rights or are you trying to get Administration rights without prompting the user (which is not possible)?

Comment: If the sec option is not possible so what should I do with the app to let the standard user to run it without entering administrator credentials?

Comment: Whether a program can display the UAC elevation prompt for a standard user is a configuration setting.  I think the usual way programmers get in trouble is by trying to disable UAC.  Which doesn't disable UAC, it disables the prompt.  Ask at superuser.com

Comment: If an ordinary application requires admin privilege then a standard user *can't* run it without providing admin credentials.  That's a basic security requirement, so you can't magic it away by putting the application in a special place.  The correct solution depends on the situation; in particular, you need to answer the question "why does the application require admin access to run"?

Comment: If it has a genuine need for admin access, then it needs to be a system service, or perhaps a combination of a system service and an application.  In many cases, though, applications only need admin access because they haven't been designed properly (e.g., they write log files to the wrong place) and if these problems are fixed then the admin access is no longer needed.  (Yet another scenario is applications that don't need admin access, but Windows mistakenly thinks they do; in this case the solution is to give the application a manifest.)

Comment: Thanks Harry, that was the problem.